# How can I do a Lua script for GHUB in order to switch my keyboard's lightning once my pc goes in stand by mode?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software, standby, logitech-led-illumination-sdk

I have recently bought a new logitech keyboard and I want it to change lights whenever my pc goes in stand by mode... I have seen that you can assign scripts to your light profiles in GHUB but these scripts have to be written in Lua and I do'nt know any of it... is there a way to do so?

I have tried looking online but looks like no one wants their kb to switch lights after pc goes on stand by

Comment: GHUB profile is chosen automatically depending on the game currently running, each profile has its own illumination.  So, you can select different illumination for different .exe-files (without writing Lua scripts at all).  I didn't experiment with stand-by mode although.

Comment: You should download logitech LED illumitation SDK and write a program for modifying lightning of the keyboard.  SDK does not use Lua, it is available in C#, Java(?) and C.   Lua is used in LGS/GHUB scripts, these scripts are usually used for simulating key press events, but these scripts don't have ability to control keyboard lightning.